# What is the appropriate directory for sites and apps when setting up public multi-purpose home server?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, virtualhost

I'm still very new and green to the Linux world. I'm doing this as a learning experience. I've seen a lot of tutorials that walk you through setting up a multi-purpose home server. 
They all seem to fall short as far as giving examples or suggestions on how to structure a multi-site web server or multiple web applications and dump everything into the default web root `/var/www/html/`.

Is this the appropriate directory to install or configure multiple site document folders or web-based apps? I've worked with web-based apps and sites in a shared host environment which points to `/home/~johndoe/public_html` or something similar. Keep in mind; I would like to have this "home server" public-facing for file-sharing with friends, not just family.

As far as the machine, I'm working with, it's a custom built box with an Intel I5 processor and 16gb of ram, 500gb SSD primary drive, and two 1TB WD drives set up in RAID1 (if I remember correctly).

I've edited the above questions, etc in hopes to clarify what I'm asking. Another example of what I'd like to do in Linux similar to how I have my test site structure; since posting this I've been using XAMPP on Windows 10. In my htdocs folder, I've created virtual hosts with a public_html folder in each such as "site1.local/public_html", "site2.local/public_html", etc. I'm not sure if this is typical, however, it seems to work in my case.

Please let me know if this needs further clarification.

Comment: "They all seem to fall short"... fall short of what?